# named urls of the form {%url 'somenamedurl' %} in django not working

Tags: python, django

That named url worked before, i put another django project and installed few packages like pyjasper etc. My bad I didnt do virtualenv.

Now the other project is not important. Current version of django I am using is 1.6.2.
I am not able to trace the error.

It says error rendering

```
SyntaxError at /dashboard/
invalid syntax (views.py, line 7)
```

Error during template rendering
In template D:\djangoprojects\prmanager\templates\menu.html, error at line 3

```
1   {% load static %}
2   <li class="active">
3       <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">
4           <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
5       </a>
6   </li>
7   
8   <li class="treeview">
9       <a href="#">
10          <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> <span>Work Orders</span>
11          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
12      </a>
13      <ul class="treeview-menu">
```

Notice line number 3. I tried named them with quotes and without.

Not able to find which views.py its talking about. Because in the dashboard app, there is no line no 7 in views.py

Can somebody throw some light as to where to look for the bug. If this info is not sufficient, please let me know and I will post the same.

What I do know is, what was working before, stopped working.

Edit 
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'prmanager.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),

    url(r'^materials/', include('materials.urls')),
    url(r'^suppliers/', include('suppliers.urls')),
    url(r'^purchaserequest/', include('purchaserequest.urls')),
    url(r'^purchaseorder/', include('purchaseorder.urls'), name="purchaseorder"),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^getSuppliersJson/', 'commontools.tools.getSuppliersJson', name="getSuppliersJson"),
    url(r'^getPOJson/', 'commontools.tools.getPOJson', name="getPOJson"),


) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Dashboard app's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('dashboard.views',   
    url(r'^$', 'dashboard', name="dashboard"),
    #url(r'^newpurchaserequest/', 'newpurchaserequest', name="newpurchaserequest"),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already placing the error,

```
SyntaxError at /dashboard/
invalid syntax (views.py, line 7)
```

So problem is in your views.py file at line 7.

**Update:**

you are included dashboard urls.py, but at the same time you used `$`. It is not matching next sub patterns.

yes now problem is here `url(r'^dashboard/$', include('dashboard.urls')),` use this `url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),`

app configuration is like this,

**In root urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
)
```

**In dashboard app:**

**In urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('dashboard.views',   
    url(r'^$', 'dashboard', name="dashboard"),
)
```

**In views.py:**

```
def dashboard(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you, there is no line no 7 in views.py in dashboard app. it has only 5 lines.                                                `code`from django.shortcuts import render  

    def dashboard(request):  
 context = {}  
 return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html', context)     `code`

Comment: dhana thank you, but i posted the code, but, it doesnt format properly

Comment: yes now problem is here `url(r'^dashboard/$', include('dashboard.urls')),` use this `url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),`

Comment: Dhana by any chance are you in south india. I am from chennai

Answer (score 0):

You should be using this syntax:

```
{% url 'dashboard' as dashboard_url %}
<a href="{{ dashboard_url }}">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried that and it gives the same issue.

Comment: What does your urls.py look like? What view is it pointing to?

Comment: davko i just posted the urls.py in the question section. I want to mention that, these used to work fine until a day before.

Comment: Have you tried <a href="{% url 'dashboard.views.dashboard' %}">?

Comment: Davko thank you for your assistance. Time and again one thing is proved, "if a bug is too difficult to find, its a pretty simple bug". I just made a mistake not worth mentioning in stackoverflow. there are 14 apps in this project, and in one views.py of one app, there was an error. You see, I am not ashamed, because it came because of an svn update I did and somebody had commmitted the same.